# WebGL on telegram games?

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, telegram, unity-webgl

Telegram games should be [in HTML5](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#games), but I've no experience in it. If I make a 2D game in Unity (I'll need some learnings) with C# and export it as WebGL, will it work in  telegram?

I know the browser should support WebGL.

Does telegram in-app browser supports WebGL? couldn't find anything anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: the reason I ask this is because I don't know Unity, WebGL and HTML5.. If I knew I could test it, but I have to start learning those and I need to know if it will work after lots of effort

Answer (score 0):

Probably will not work.

Better choose an HTML5 Game Engines

https://html5gameengine.com/

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/the-top-html5-canvas-game-engines.html